# Angular Testing - createSpyObj method not called

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I have one Angular component and one service. In the component I have a method which calls one method of the service. At the component test I try to create a mock for the service, then when I call the method of the component I would like to check if the service method was called from the component.

The component:

```js
export class TestComponent {

  constructor(private testService: TestService) {}

  edit(): void {
    this.testService.getCase('id').subscribe(console.log);
  }
}
```

The service:

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TestService {

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
  ) { }

  getCase(id: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>(`url`);
  }
}
```

And the test:

```js
describe('TestComponent', () => {
  let component: TestComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestComponent>;
  const testServiceMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('TestService', ['getCase']);
  
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ TestComponent ],
      providers: [
        { provide: TestService, useValue: testServiceMock },
      ]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('expect service has been called', () => {
    spyOn(component, 'edit');
    component.edit();
    expect(component.edit).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(testServiceMock.getCase).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

This line is constantly failing:
`expect(testServiceMock.getCase).toHaveBeenCalled();`

`TestComponent expect service has been called FAILED Error: Expected spy TestService.getCase to have been called.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to delegate calls to actual implementation:

```js
spyOn(component, 'edit').and.callThrough();
```

---

https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction#section-Spies:_%3Ccode%3Eand.callThrough%3C/code%3E

Answer (score 3):

Since the `edit` method is a spy, the actual implementation never gets called so the `getCase` spy never gets called as well. In order to resolve this please use the `edit` method spy with `callThrough()`. This forces the actual implementation to be called.

```
spyOn(component,'edit').and.callThrough()
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create inject the service in the second beforeEach() and set it to a variable.

```
const testServiceMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('TestService', 
['getCase']);
let testServiceSpy;

beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
    testServiceSpy = TestBed.inject(TestService);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
});


it('expect service has been called', () => {
    spyOn(component, 'edit');
    component.edit();
    expect(component.edit).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(testServiceSpy.getCase).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```